# How to remove oscillation knob from fan

Tags: appliances, fans, knobs

A friend and I are trying to repair a vintage Hitachi oscillating desk fan. To get the cover off, it appears the oscillation knob has to be removed. The knob seems to be too big to force trough the hole in the cover.

It has a screw inside it, but whatever way we try to turn the screw, the entire knob just turns along with it.

How are you supposed to take this cover and/or knob off?

[image: Desk fan cover]

Comment: Can you just hold the knob to keep it from turning, while attempting to turn the screw?

Comment: Small appliance questions are off topic here.  See the [help].

Answer (score 2):

Try the screw again with the knob pressed in (as if the oscillation was activated).

In a typical old school fan the knob doubles as a way to manually move the oscillation mechanism of the fan in case you want to disable the oscillation and it's in the wrong position. When oscillation is active then it is engaged with the motor through some gearing.

If that doesn't work you can try to move the fan to one extreme of the oscillation and then hold that in place while you try the screw in the hopes that the mechanism is held in place that way.

Comment: That would put the force of the screwdriver on the mechanism, which could damage it. The knob needs to be held in place.